# GreenDao why using Integer instead of int?

Tags: greendao

I want to know that why greendao uses Integer instead of int?

I find that ExampleDaoGenerator generator the entity int field are all Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Integer is used for fields that may be NULL. For properties configured with `notNull()` int should be used.